# UIButton in subview not receiving touch after NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have 2 custom UIViews that i'm adding to my UIViewController and then aligning them using NSLayoutConstraint. After I apply the NSLayoutConstraint on the UIViewController view then UIButtons in the custom UIViews no longer receive touch events.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    navigationBar = [[DtNavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,45)];
    [navigationBar setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:navigationBar];

    switchBar = [[DtSwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,44)];
    [switchBar setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:switchBar];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[navigationBar(45)]-0-[switchBar(44)]-(>=100)-|"
                                                                      options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft metrics:nil
                                                                        views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(switchBar, navigationBar)]];
}
```

Both DtNavigationBar and DtSwitch have UIButton views that still show up in the right place but no longer responds to touch.

If I remove the addConstraints part (and manually place the views) then the buttons work fine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that, having elected to use constraints, you are not using *enough* constraints. You have ambiguous layout.

To test this hypothesis, run the app, and pause in the debugger and enter this in the lldb console:

```
po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]
```

The words AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT will appear somewhere in the response.

You need sufficient constraints to make those words go away. You must fully determine the vertical and horizontal position *and* width *and* height of everything in the story.