# Nested UITableViews no longer work in iOS7

Tags: uitableview, nested, ios7

I've got a nested table inside the first cell of another table. It worked great, until I recompiled for iOS7, and now the inner table's row selection events are no longer being handled by the inner table's delegate methods.

I'm stumped. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like switching to AutoLayout is the culprit. I guess I don't have enough constraints on the superview of my outer table view. I added the missing width and height constraints to my outer table view, but I can't seem to add those to its parent view in IB. Please check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629673/uibutton-in-subview-not-receiving-touch-after-nslayoutconstraint

Comment: put some line of code please which gives better idea for your problem

Answer (score 1):

I use this technique very often and it still works in iOS 7. Keep in mind that because of how constraints work for scrollviews (in this case tableviews) you need the content of the inner tableview to define the height of it (I'm assuming the inner table is fixed so height = contentSize).

I usually extend UITableView for this purpose into something like this so that it works well with constraints in this scenario:

```
@implementation ExpandedTableView

- (void)reloadData
{
    [super reloadData];
    [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
}

- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
    return self.contentSize;
}

@end
```

Also, check out my pod with some helpers to easily create dynamic height table cells:
https://github.com/fer662/UITableViewHelper

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if that's the case, but make sure your nester table view is added to the cell.contentView of your  first cell. As UITableViewCell hierarchy changed on iOS7, you now need to add every controls to the cell contentView.